# How to send all email from a Rails app asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a rails app that uses delayed_job.

Whilst DJ gives me a really easy way to setup delays on emails, is there any way to globally configure my app to send all email asynchronously regardless?  The reason for this is that I have some gems that send email and don't want to have to modify them to accept DJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Delayed job mailer](http://github.com/andersondias/delayed_job_mailer) looks like a good fit for what you want to do.